# Databricks: merge dataframe into sql datawarehouse table

Tags: python, databricks

Are there any method where I can upsert into a SQL datawarehouse table ?
Suppose I have a Azure SQL datawarehouse table :
col1   col2    col3 
2019   09       10
2019   10       15

I have a dataframe 
col1  col2   col3
2019   10     20
2019   11     30

Then merge into the original table of Azure data warehouse table

col1 col2 col3
2019 09    10 
2019 10    20 
2019 11    30

Thanks for everyone idea

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Great question.  I need to do the same thing in a couple of days; just need to finish off one preliminary thing first.  Try the concept below and see if it works for you.

Write to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"          -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName" -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"      -> "dbo.Clients",
  "user"         -> "username",
  "password"     -> "xxxxxxxx"
))

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

collection.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(config)
```

Please give me feedback and let me know if it works for you.  I have to do this very soon.

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases-azure.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-connect-to-sql-database

Comment: SaveMode.Append will only append no matter it has duplicate records or not

Answer (score 0):

you can save the output in a file and then use the stored procedure activity from azure data factory for the upsert. Just a small procedure which will upsert the values from the file.  I am assuming that you are using the Azure data factory here.

Answer (score 0):

See this great article from Data Mastery for a reusable PySpark Type 2 SCD function to write from Databricks to a dedicated SQL pool(Formally Azure DW)! Your welcome :)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/databricks-pyspark-type-2-scd-function-azure-pools-rory-mcmanus/